# Converting xml files into java objects by using json

Tags: java, xml, json

I've been trying to convert XML file to java objects efficiently but I haven't succeeded yet. I have seen JAXB notation, and a few others but they havent looked efficient to me and I need to use json. I need help with efficient code example.

Comment: Good to hear that you have attempted this. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Use JAXB is the better option to proceed further for marshalling and unmarshalling in java

Comment: You could have at the very least provided an XML snippet you're trying to convert and the corresponding java class.

Comment: i tried unmarshalling by using JAXB but i had an exception about resource finding. it means i locate the xml file to wrong place. i located it webcontent in eclipse project but resuorce can't be found

Comment: I handled the problem. Thanks a lot to that tries t help. I used JAXB and with a little difference; importing the other version of the same named libray. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do not invent the wheel. These libraries (GSON, Jackson...) are pretty fast, tested and have huge community. If it was easy to write things better, it would have been already done.

And this is not really a question ;-)

Comment: i tried unmarshalling by using JAXB but i had an exception about resource finding. it means i locate the xml file to wrong place. i located it webcontent in eclipse project but resuorce can't be found

Comment: update your question (exception, file hierarchy etc.). From your current post it is really hard to guess what went wrong and what you expect.

Comment: JAXBContext context1 = JAXBContext.newInstance(JavaObject.class);final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context1.createUnmarshaller();

  File file = new File("sample-xml.xml");
  
  final JavaObject object = (JavaObject) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(file));

Comment: in this case, i get file not found exception

Comment: and where is the file, if in src directory, tham 1) make sure, that you have maven resources polugin configured 2) you should load it using classloader.getResource(). Also file has method getAbsolutePath, so printout the path and make sure, that the file is there.

Comment: @erdysson - I would recommend loading the XML as an `InputStream` via a `ClassLoader` rather than a `File` for your use case:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Comment: I handled the problem. Thanks a lot to that tries t help. I used JAXB and with a little difference; importing the other version of the same named libray. thanks